# Retrieve next row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to compare whether the string "reject" comes before the string "approve". For example,

```
+----+----------+
| cid| Status   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | pending  |
| 1  | reject   |
| 1  | pending  |
| 1  | approve  |
| 2  | pending  |
| 2  | reject   |
| 2  | approve  |
| 3  | pending  |
| 3  | approve  |
| 3  | reject   |
| 4  | approve  |
| 4  | pending  |
| 4  | approve  |
+----+----------+
```

Then from the above table, I would like to return the id 2 because the string approve comes directly after the string reject. My thought so far is to create another column which contain next row value. So after the sql query, it would be like the following: (Note that the id 3 is not included because even though after string reject comes a string approve, but it's not from the same id).

```
+----+----------+------------+
| cid| Status   | Next Value |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  | pending  | reject     |
| 1  | reject   | pending    |
| 1  | pending  | approve    |
| 1  | approve  | pending    |
| 2  | pending  | reject     |
| 2  | reject   | approve    |
| 2  | approve  | pending    |
| 3  | pending  | approve    |
| 3  | approve  | reject     |
| 3  | reject   | approve    |
| 4  | approve  | pending    |
| 4  | pending  | approve    |
| 4  | approve  | (null)     |
+----+----------+------------+
```

With an idea as above, I'm still not sure on how to write the Query and need help constructing it. I've tried to search but most of the answers are in SQL Server using lag function. Additionally, any other approach would be greatly appreciated. (Note: There's an ID column which represents the number of row 1,2,...,12,etc. Also, there's a column of date, thus, the input status will be in order.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering, and you don't seem to have such a column.

Comment: (Edit: There's a column of date, so the status will be in order for each CID. Hope that helps. )

Comment: MySQL 8.0 does have lag() function. Otherwise, self join using cid and the date field.

Comment: how would you write that? And why use the date column?

Comment: Because there no such thing like "before" in SQL, unless you define it using a column (or multiple columns) for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server doesn't support window functions like `LAG()`, you can use this:

```
select r.id, r.cid
from mytable r
join mytable a
  on  a.cid = r.cid
  and a.id = (
    select min(id)
    from mytable a2
    where a2.cid = r.cid
      and a2.id  > r.id
  )
where r.Status = 'reject'
  and a.Status = 'approve'
```

This will return a row with `Status = 'reject'` which is directly followed by by a row
with `Status = 'approve'`.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rhZomY6hBCHfBjQiFWb4vi/0)

If you only need to know `cid` without duplicates, then use

```
select distinct r.cid
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works perfectly fine. But you can explain further on the [and a.id = (
    select min(id)
    from mytable a2
    where a2.cid = r.cid
      and a2.id  > r.id
  )] statement

Comment: Like how does that return all the id when the it says min(id) which as far as I know would only return one value. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, not sure where tho.

Comment: @noobyz The subquery is *correlated*. That means it depends on the values from `r` (see inner WHERE clause: `a2.cid = r.cid and a2.id  > r.id`), and thus will return different values (which is always the next higher `id` for the same `cid`).

Comment: Oh okay that totally makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select cid
from t
where status in ('reject', 'approve')
group by cid
having min(case when status = 'reject' then date end) < max(case when status = 'approve' then date end);
```

This is comparing the earliest reject date to the latest approve date, and returning `cid`s where the reject is before the approve.

Comment: can you explain further on the having clause? Also, when I ran the program, it outputs 1 instead of 2.

Comment: Don't you miss a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: your Query returns cid which has reject and approve status after it. But what the result I wanted is to return cid which has status reject followed DIRECTLY with the status approve. which in our example, cid = 2